# using word2vec with heroku cloud platform

Tags: heroku, semantics, word2vec

how can i use word2vec with heroku or any other cloud platform. I want to store my trained data set on cloud platform. so that every query can be retrieved through there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to take a look at [Floydhub](https://www.floydhub.com/), which is a Deep Learning PaaS (dubbed by its creators as "Heroku for Deep Learning").
Specifically, I think you may want to take a look at this [fastText](https://github.com/floydhub/fastText) example.

See [Stock2Vec](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/stock2vec-from-ml-to-p-e-2e6ba407c24) for an example of a Word2Vec model trained on Floydhub.